# Trouble Scraping .HTM File

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack, web-scraping

I have just begun scraping basic text off web pages, and am currently using the HTMLAgilityPack C# library.  I had some success with boxscores off rivals.yahoo.com (sports is my thing so why not scrape something interesting?) but I am stuck on NHL's game summary pages.  I think this is kind of an interesting problem so I would post it here.

The page I am testing is:
http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20102011/GS020079.HTM

Upon first glance, it seems like basic text with no ajax or stuff to mess up a basic scraper.  Then I realize I can't right click due to some javascript, so I work around that.  I right click in firefox and get the xpath of the home team using XPather and I get:

```
/html/body/table[@id='MainTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[@id='StdHeader']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[@id='Home']/tbody/tr[3]/td
```

When I try to grab that node / inner text, htmlagilitypack won't find it.  Does anyone see anything strange in the page's source code that might be stopping me?

I am new to this and still learning how people might stop me from scraping, any tips or tricks are gladly appreciated!

p.s. I observe all site rules regarding bots, etc, but I noticed this strange behavior and saw it as a challenge.

Comment: nice, thanks for the tip about XPather, will have to use.

Comment: can anyone else go to that page and try to get the xpath for the home team (columbus on top right) and paste it in here so I can compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think unless my xpath knowledge is heaps flawed(probably) the problem is with the /tbody node in your xpath expression.

When I do

```
 string test = string.Empty;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\gs.htm");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(sr);
sr.Close();
sr = null;
string xpath = @"//table[@id='Home']/tr[3]/td";
test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

That works fine.. returns a
"COLUMBUS BLUE JACKETSGame 5 Home Game 3"
which I hope is the string you wanted.

Examining the html I couldn't find a /tbody.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it appears that my xpaths have tbody's in them.  When I remove these tbodys manually from the xpath, HTMLAgilityPack can handle it fine.

I'd still like to know why I am getting invalid xpaths, but for now I have answered my question.

Comment: probably related to either the browser or the xpather app, i'm going to check it out sounds interesting.